# Are Aragorn and Arwen cousins?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

I was looking at the Noldor House of Finwë descendancy and on one side it shows Arwen, daughter of Elrond as we all know.  But I didn't know this part: the other side breaks off into Aragorn as a descendant of Elros - Elrond's twin brother.  Does that make them cousins?

Comment: The first Appendix to LoTR recounts the Tale of Aragorn and Arwen, and tells of their first meeting when Arwen says: "Then we are akin from afar".

Comment: Aragorn definitely has Aunt Lindsay’s nose. Wait, sorry, wrong universe.

Comment: Kissin' cousins...

Comment: To everyone here using family trees off the webz, I'm not sure where these find their source? For all I know, the books would be the only sources that may decide this. But I know that most of the names in these family trees are never mentioned.

Comment: Near duplicate of http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/91166/how-much-elven-ancestry-does-aragorn-have/91169#91169; the first answer goes into great detail about Aragorn's ancestry.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Using the family-tree from http://lotrproject.com/, by my quick-count it seems Arwen and Aragorn II are [first-cousins either 62 or 67 times removed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin#Cousin_chart), depending on whether you go through Aragorn's great x 14 grandfather (Arvedui) or great x 14 grandmother (Firiel) who both descended from Elendil (Arvedui on the Isildur side, Firiel on the Anarion side).

Hence Elendil is Aragorn's great x 38 grandfather as well as Aragorn's great x 43 grandfather.

Comment: For fun, you could try sticking a few more greats in [wolfram alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=great+great+great+great+great+great+great+great+great+great+great+great+great+grandfather%27s+brother%27s+daughter)

Answer (score 45):

The short answer is yes, they're directly related (first cousins) albeit separated by a very *considerable* age gap.

This handy family tree from [The Encyclopaedia of Arda](http://www.glyphweb.com/arda/e/elrond.html) should be helpful to you:

[image: Arwen Aragorn]

Please note that the *dotted* line between Elros and Aragorn represents many thousands of years of lineage on Aragorn's side of the family.

Comment: The men of Numenor are long-lived, but this still represents something like 50 *generations* of descent between Elros and Aragorn. (We could get a rough idea how many by counting the Kings of Numenor and later of Arnor, but I can't be bothered to go get my copy of LOTR and do that just now.) In real-world terms it would be like marrying someone you shared an ancestor with about 1000 years ago. Any two people from (say) the same European country are likely to have a common ancestor if you go this far back.

Comment: @RoyalCanadianBandit - Precisely. http://www.theguardian.com/world/2008/mar/25/barackobama1 Obama = related to Clinton, the Queen, Churchill, Tony Blair, George Bush, etc etc/

Comment: Aragorn's descent is a little more complex: his relationship to Elros was actually through the eldest daughter of the fourth king of Numenor, so he's a good deal more distant than the simple chart above may lead you to think.

Comment: @JimmyShelter - Yes, the chart is a bit of fluff designed to illustrate the foolishness of trying to backtrack familial relations over millenniun. At any point this lineage could easily have been illegitimised by a bored queen and a bottle of cheap bordeaux.

Comment: @Richard: And then acts of love consummated, "Oh, you enormous Scotsman," et cetera. And these letters are dated November and December 1460, which, Harry, in relation to your date of birth, is precisely nine months...

Comment: I'm not sure 50 generations of difference still "counts" as first cousins, but then, I don't what that would be called anyway.

Comment: @PaulDraper, the technical term for generational differences of this sort is "removes", eg. if your grandfather was my great-grandfather, we'd be "first cousins once removed".  Aragorn and Arwen are "first cousins fifty-someodd times removed".

Comment: @Richard: By the same token, a king or prince with a fondness for the ladies could easily have a few dozen illegitimate children and spread the lineage far and wide.

Comment: Will you please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cousin for some basic information? The are cousins, but not first cousins. Sheesh.

Comment: @Mark: or to put it another way, your uncle is your brother once removed ;-) So Elrond is Aragorn's 50x-great-uncle (his direct ancestor's brother), and as you say Arwen is his first cousin 50x removed.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast: "When the cousins are not the same generation, they are described as "removed". In this case, __the smaller number of generations to the common ancestor is used to determine the degree__, and the difference in generations determines the number of times removed."  So the smaller number of generations to the common ansestors is one, so they're first cousins.  Did _you_ read the page you linked?

Comment: Worth mentioning that Arwen should have ~50% of Earendil/Elwing DNA, while Aragorn would have ~0.5^61 + 0.5^66 -> ~0.00000000000000004472334% of Earendil/Elwing DNA, enough difference that inbreeding it not a serious concern.

Comment: Re: DNA comparison, remember that the Elrond-Celebrian relationship has a bit of relatedness, because Celebrian is Finwe's great-granddaughter, (Finwe, Finarfin, Galadrial, Celebrian) and Elrond is his great-great-great-grandson (Finwe, Fingolfin, Turgon, Idril, Earandil, Elrond)

Answer (score 9):

Very distant first cousins, many many times removed.

Comment: many thousand years removed.

Comment: Yep, quite the older woman.

Comment: Those dunedain sure love their cougars!