# Why do the Elves not have more offspring?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, elves

Elves in Tolkien's legendarium are a very, very long-lived race, essentially immortal. But, yet, they don't seem to have a lot of offspring. When looking at the family trees of some of the well known Elven characters, the numbers of their offspring seem to range in what compares to humans in the here and now: i.e. low single digits. When *actually*, it would be easy for a 3000 year old Elf to have dozens if not hundreds of sons and daughters...

- Why would Elves who live for millennia not have more offspring?

Are they not interested in raising more children after the first couple? Can they control their fertility somehow?

Comment: Have children and see if you have the same question.

Comment: 1. They are immortal. 2. They're not Targaryens

Comment: @Edlothiad [At least They try to be](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/56788/are-aragorn-and-arwen-cousins)